# Adding tax to a form field

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need need help with a Invoice I'm making.
I've created a text form field of number type and bookmarked it.
I'd like to run a macro on exit that reads the number in the form field, add 5% to it and then puts the new number in the form field.

This is my guess at a solution:

```
Sub Five()
'
' Five Macro
' Add 5% to the Unit Price
'
    Dim CurrentCell As Currency
    Const Percent = 1.05
    Set CurrentCell = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.SelectCell
    Set CurrentCell = (CurrentCell * Percent)
    Options.ReplaceSelection = True
    With Selection
        .TypeText Text:=CurrentCell
        .TypeParagraph
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say you want to run the macro "on exit", do you mean just as the document is closed?

Comment: From the VBA you have, I would say this is an Excel question. If so, you need to re-tag the question. Either way, please clarify exactly what type of "form" you are using

Answer (score 0):

Go to the VBA editor (Alt-F11) and double click on "ThisWorkbook" in the left hand pane.

Then paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Five
End Sub
```

This code will run when the selection changes (i.e. when you have left a field).

As written, it will run your macro if you have left cell A1 but you could change the Range arguments to another field (or fields) you which to monitor.